# Replace special qoutes with normal

Tags: vb.net, replace, utf-8

In VB.NET how do I replace special opening and closing double quotes (“ and ”) with ASCII quotes (").

Ive tried

```
s = s.replace("“", """")
```

but it seems that Visual Studio consider the “ quote in my code to be a normal quote leaving me with an invalid statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately VB.NET doesn't support escape sequences but you can use `ChrW()` to specify code point:

```
s = s.Replace(ChrW(&H201C), """")
```

That's for <kbd>“</kbd>, code for <kbd>”</kbd> is &H201D. Note that using code points you're free to search & replace any Unicode character (not just what VB.NET has an escape for - like <kbd>"</kbd>).

For complete list see: http://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a quotation mark inside a string, VB doesn’t know whether the quotation mark is supposed to end the string or not. In C#, this would be fixed by escaping the quotation mark, i.e. in place of `"""` you’d write `"\""`. In VB, the same is done by doubling the quotation mark, i.e. `""""`.

Back to your curly quote. The same as for straight quotes applies according to the VB language specification (¶1.6.4). So to write a curly quote in code, try the following:

```
s = Replace(s , "““", "&#8220;")
```

a second way: `s = Replace(s , ChrW(&H201C), "&#8220;")`